# Magento module creation, gives error: DOMDocument::loadXML(): XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document in Entity

Tags: module, magento-2.0.2

I am new to magento and just installed magento2 in my system.
I tried creating a new module but facing error which I am unable to handle. Please help...I am getting error as
[image: There has been an error processing your request]
Following is the logs that are generated in var > report folder

```
a:4:{i:0;s:189:
"Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document in Entity, line: 11 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\magento\framework\Config\Dom.php on line 365"
;i:1;s:5368:"
#0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'DOMDocument::lo...', 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs...', 365, Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\magento\framework\Config\Dom.php(365): DOMDocument->loadXML('<!-- \r\n<?xml ve...')
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\magento\framework\Config\Dom.php(121): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->_initDom('<!-- \r\n<?xml ve...')
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\magento\framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem.php(148): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->merge('<!-- \r\n<?xml ve...')
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\magento\framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem.php(127): Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem->_readFiles(Object(Magento\Framework\Config\FileIterator))
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\var\generation\Magento\Framework\App\Route\Config\Reader\Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem->read('frontend')
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\Route\Config.php(82): Magento\Framework\App\Route\Config\Reader\Proxy->read('frontend')
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\Route\Config.php(98): Magento\Framework\App\Route\Config->_getRoutes('frontend')
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\magento\framework\Url.php(581): Magento\Framework\App\Route\Config->getRouteFrontName(NULL, 'frontend')
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\magento\framework\Url.php(428): Magento\Framework\Url->_getRouteFrontName()
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\magento\framework\Url.php(706): Magento\Framework\Url->getBaseUrl(Array)
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\magento\framework\Url.php(867): Magento\Framework\Url->getRouteUrl('', Array)
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\magento\framework\Url.php(819): Magento\Framework\Url->createUrl('', Array)
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\magento\module-store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor.php(73): Magento\Framework\Url->getUrl('', Array)
#14 [internal function]: Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#15 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(68): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#16 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#17 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\magento\framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#18 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#19 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(68): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#20 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#21 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\magento\module-page-cache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin.php(68): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#22 [internal function]: Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#23 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(68): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#24 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(136): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#25 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\magento\module-page-cache\Model\App\FrontController\VarnishPlugin.php(55): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#26 [internal function]: Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\VarnishPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(141): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#28 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\var\generation\Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#29 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php(115): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#30 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#31 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#32 {main}";s:3:"url";s:9:"/magento/";s:11:"script_name";s:18:"/magento/index.php";}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like there is something wrong with XML or setup version in your files. Check the setup version in **'module.xml'** file. 
`dom.php` file is "document object model"
Check all the files syntax, extension's and codes.

Even clear the static cache and enable your module by using the following command in cmdline..

> "php bin/magento module:enable --clear-static-content Abc_ModuleName"

where Abc is your vendor name in code folder &
ModuleName is the name of your Module
your directory should look like `"rootDir>app>code>Abc(vendor)>ModuleName(your Module)"`

also run the set-up upgrade command

> "php bin/magento setup:upgrade"

Your module should work properly after these steps...

Comment: thanks neighboursoft. The information really gave me a solution to my problem

Comment: i have done same things but not working.